# Git - Can automatic merges disappear with changes?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Guys this question is more conceitual than technical, I guess.

I have the feeling that sometimes when all team members work on the same branch, after several automatic merges in that branch, Git will get lost (or the team will) and remove some important the changes from the last version. So if someone clones the repository, I believe some of the changes will not be there and give the impression they have disappeared.

I'm not sure if it really happens this way, but I believe I've seen this before in some projects I were in. Reading the history of changes in that branch, the removal of those chunks of code doesn't seem to have been made by a human ("this is not important, I will remove all the changes in this file from an specific commit").

My guess is that Git believes that some changes are older than another one and just overwrites them with something else. In fact these changes can be older, but for the team that was working on it, it wasn't clear and they didn't understand what happened when the code have gone. They realize they are working on an older version of the code but it may take some time to get noticed.

Have any of you seen this before or had the same impression? What phenomenon is that or what could explain it? It's probably the team using the tool the wrong way, but maybe Git don't know how to resolve some situations.

Thanks in advance, links will be appreciated (I have looked for explanations, but they always talk about very generic problems)

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain this is a usage problem :-)

It is hard though from your description to get an idea what could be going on. If you have some specific commits that you know went missing, you should try find them using git log --all maybe someone messed up your head and therefore you don't see the commits when doing a "plain" git log?